# An inequality of determinant

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

$A_i \in M_n(\mathbb{R}), 1 \leq i \leq k, \ A_i A_j = A_j A_i, 1 \leq i,j \leq k$,

Prove that $$\det(\sum_{i=1}^k A_i^2) \geq 0$$

When $k=2$, let $\widetilde{A_2}=A_2 + \epsilon I $ s.t $ \widetilde{A_2}$ is invertible, then $ A_1 , \widetilde{A_2}$ can commute too.

So $ \det(A_1^2+\widetilde{A_2}^2) \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \det((A_1 \widetilde{A_2}^{-1})^2+I) \geq 0 $.

So we only need to prove that $\det(A^2+I) \geq 0$.

Let $ \lambda_1,\lambda_2 \dots \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, then the eigenvalues of $A^2+1$ are $ \lambda_1^2+1,\lambda_2^2+1 \dots \lambda_n^2+1$. Since the product of conjugate eigenvalues are nonnegative and $\lambda_i^2+1 \geq 0, \ \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$, so it is true. Then let $\epsilon\to 0$ and we can get the conclusion.

But I don't know how to generalize it. I also know that $ A_i$ can be upper-diagonalized by the same matrice and have a idea that sees the $\det(A^2+I)$ as a function $f(t)=\det(A^2+tI)$, but I don't know how to continue. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the eigenvalues of $A$ might be complex, e.g., $\lambda = 2i$ in which case $\lambda^2+1 = -3 < 0$.

Comment: But the complex eigenvalues are conjugate, for example, the -2i is also the eigenvalues.

Comment: You are right...

Comment: Maybe one could work with the exponential function since $\exp(\sum_i A_i^2) = \prod_i\exp(A_i^2)$ (which holds as the matrices commute).

Comment: But how to connect to determinant? Since $\det(\exp(A))=\exp(tr A)$

Comment: This is even hard when one assumes that, say, $A_1$ has only distinct eigenvalues. Then the same holds for the other matrices and the eigenvectors are the same (not so the eigenvalues). Then the determinant takes the form$$\prod_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_{ij}^2,$$where $\lambda_{ij}$ is the $j$th eigenvalue of $A_i$. I think the only information we have here is that for each $i$ and ech $j$ we either have $\lambda_{ij}\in\mathbb R$ or there exists a unique $l(i,j)\neq j$ such that $\lambda_{ij} = \overline{\lambda_{i,l(i,j)}}$. This then has a combinatorial flavour.

Comment: cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357082/why-is-the-determinant-of-sum-i-1n-a-i2-non-negative/1357579#1357579

Comment: Yeh, I have ever had this idea. Since they can be upper-diagonalized by the same matrice, it can be translated to this problem,but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Thank you! This is a beautiful solution!